# Who is the typical speaker at an academic workshop (in the field of Economics)?

Tags: economics, workshop

I've been asked to help with an academic workshop in the field of Economics and I was wondering whether most speakers who are invited to such events are faculty members or PhD students (apart from keynote speakers, which I guess are usual big-caliber people so mostly full professors with high reputation)? Is there anything like a standard type of speaker (Phd student or Professor) or does that fully depend on the organizers?

I know it's probably a dumb question, go easy on me. Thanks!!

Comment: You're probably better off discussing this with the rest of the organising committee. There's no hard and fast rule. However, don't invite a big shot just because they're a big shot. Invite good speakers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The focus and scope of the workshop should have a bearing on the speakers lineup.  Perhaps, that's where to start from.
This links to the (nature of targeted) audience.

Inbtw, at workshop level, the *field of Economics* can be wide!

Depending on the nature of the workshop and *field* of Economics, your speakership lineups can range from or mix of:

- graduate students
- doctorate students
- postdocs
- early career
- established academia (Professors)
- Policy makers/analysts
- (even) industry heavyweights